# Get geometry type of wms layer in openlayers

Tags: openlayers, wms

Is there anyway to get geometry type of wms layer in openlayers? If yes, please tell me how!
In my code, i defined a wms layer as following:

```
layerThuadat = new OpenLayers.Layer.WMS("Thua dat", url + "wms", 
{
      LAYERS: sLayer, STYLES: '', format: format,transparent : true
},
{
    singleTile : true, ratio : 1, isBaseLayer : true, yx :  {
        sprojection : false
    }
});

map.addLayers([layerThuadat]);
```

Thank.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand the model, I think that geometry type isnt' very much relevant for the WMS layer. WFS or VectorLayer would be the layers where your feature type would be relevant...

Why do you need the geometry type? Maybe there would be a way to solve this if I had more information.